# Join two or more tables that have no common fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables in a database

```
Project              Material Used            Document
------------        -------------------        ------------------------
PID |  Name         MID | PID |  Name          DocID | PID | Date
------------        -------------------        ------------------------
1   | A             1   |  1  |  A1            1     |  1  | 1/1/2016
2   | B             2   |  1  |  A1            2     |  1  | 1/2/2016
3   | C             3   |  1  |  A1            3     |  2  | 1/3/2016
                    4   |  2  |  A1            4     |  2  | 1/4/2016
                    5   |  2  |  A1            5     |  2  | 1/5/2016
                    6   |  3  |  A1            6     |  2  | 1/6/2016
                    7   |  3  |  A1            7     |  2  | 1/7/2016
                    8   |  3  |  A1            8     |  1  | 1/8/2016
                    9   |  3  |  A1            9     |  1  | 1/9/2016
```

How to query with the results like below ?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
PID     Project Name    MID             Material Name   DocID   Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       A               1               A1              1       1/1/2016
1       A               2               A2              2       1/2/2016
1       A               3               A3              NULL    NULL
2       B               4               B1              3       1/3/2016
2       B               5               B2              4       1/4/2016
2       B               NULL            NULL            5       1/5/2016
2       B               NULL            NULL            6       1/6/2016
2       B               NULL            NULL            7       1/7/2016
3       C               6               C1              8       1/8/2016
3       C               7               C2              9       1/9/2016
3       C               8               C3              NULL    NULL
3       C               9               C4              NULL    NULL
```

PID in Material and Document table is Foreign Key.

I am using Microsoft SQL 2008.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Adjust the sample data to make things a bit trickier, remove one or two rows from Document, and add another row with DocId 11.

Comment: Those `Name`s and `Date`s come from nowhere. What exactly are you trying to do? If there's no relationship between the table, there's no way to correlate the rows, period, so we need more to go on.

Comment: It is not readily apparent *why* the results should be as they are. Make sure to explain this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want lists in the columns.  You can get this using `full outer join` and `row_number()`:

```
select p.*, m.mid, m.name, d.docid, d.date 
from project p left join
     (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by mid) as seqnum
      from materials
     ) m
     on p.pid = m.pid full outer join
     (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by docid) as seqnum
      from documents
     ) d
     on p.pid =  d.pid and m.seqnum = d.seqnum;
```

Hmmm, try this version:

```
select p.*, md.mid, md.name, md.docid, md.date 
from project p left join
     (select m.id, m.name, d.docid, d.date
      from (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by mid) as seqnum
            from materials
           ) m full outer join
           (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by docid) as seqnum
            from documents
           ) d
           on p.pid =  d.pid and m.seqnum = d.seqnum
      ) md
     on p.pid = md.pid;
```

Comment: If I use your query, p.pid is always null if docID rows more than MID rows, and vice versa.